# How do you delete a key from a dictionary by only using an value entered by a user

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a student trying to complete a task on a online course and I can't find a efficient way to solve this problem.

**problem:**
Ask the user to enter 4 of their favorite foods and store them in a dictionary so that they are indexed with numbers starting from 1. Display the dictionary in full showing the index number an the item. Ask them which they want to get rid of and remove it from the list. Sort the remaining data and display it.

I have tried many possible solutions but none of them seem to work. This is what i have done so far (python 3.8):

```
foodcount=0
foods={1:0 ,2:0 ,3:0 ,4: 0}
while foodcount<4:
    food_choice=str(input('enter one of your favourite foods'))
    foodcount += 1
    foods[foodcount] = food_choice

least_fav=str(input('choos a food to delete'))
nowant=foods.index[least_fav]
del foods[nowant]
print(foods)

foods.sort(key=str)
for key,value in foods:
    print(foods(key,value))
```

I am not sure if I am misinterpreting this question but the main problem I am having is once the user enters the food they would like to delete (assume that the always enters a input that is in the dict) I can't delete the key the the food is in (can't delete the key and value). I know i have to index something but still really not sure

Thanks in advance

Comment: `del foods[least_fav]`

Comment: [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) doesn't have an `index` member function.

Comment: You should probably reverse the dictionary: the foods should be keys and the numbers should be values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dict does not support .index so you are going to have to use a for loop to iterate through a dictionary.

```
foodcount=0
foods={1:0 ,2:0 ,3:0 ,4: 0}
while foodcount<4:
    food_choice=str(input('enter one of your favourite foods'))
    foodcount += 1
    foods[foodcount] = food_choice

least_fav=str(input('choose a food to delete'))
for key, value in foods.items():
    if value == least_fav:
        foods.pop(key)
        break
print(foods)

for key,value in foods.items():
    print(key,value)
```

you already showed you know how to use a for loop to loop through the dictionary but you have to change it up a bit. If you use "foods" in a for loop it will only iterate through the keys, so 1, 2, 3, 4. if you use "foods.items()" it sets key to the keys and value to the values, which I assume you wanted.

Next you just tell it that if the value of a key is the same as what the user entered you use .pop which deletes a key:value pair based on the value.

other than that you just make sure you break when you are done so you don't get an error and use your (revised) print loop at the bottom to get the keys and values.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

If your dictionary has the foods as keys it is easier to work with them. This will work even if they misswrite the name (won't happen anything if they write it wrong):

```
foodcount=0
foods = []
while foodcount<4:
    food_choice=str(input('enter one of your favourite foods'))
    foodcount += 1
    foods.append(food_choice)

foods_dict = dict(zip(foods,[1,2,3,4]))
least_fav=str(input('choos a food to delete'))
foods_dict.pop(least_fav, None)
```

#### Output:

Foods: `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`

Least favorite: `b`

```
print(foods_dict)
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```